# Filter at the asp page is not working properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlSearch.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        if (ddlCol.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            ViewState["search"] = "";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["search"] = " and " + ddlCol.SelectedValue.ToString() + "like '%"+txtVal.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
        }

        lblTotalRecord.Text = objdl.GetScalerValue("select count(Client_id)from O_RechargeHistory_Retailer rh where client_id=" + Session["Re_id"].ToString() + "and balance>0 and Scode='PP'" + ViewState["search"] + "");

        BindData();
```

To get the totalrecord its produce error that

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: looking like your ddlCol have no value

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: dubuge your code your drop down have no value i think

Comment: if the error is in the geting the total then your session have no value

Comment: Does `ddlCol.SelectedValue.ToString()` include a trailing space? Otherwise your SQL won't be correctly formed.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to get that exception by calling `ToString()` on a `null` value.

Place breakpoints and check that the following two objects have an actual value, and are not `null`:

- `ddlCol.SelectedValue`
- `Session["Re_id"]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is defined:

```
objdl.GetScalerValue(
```

And instantiated.  It looks like this is a global variable; global variables can be challenging because ANYTHING within the code can modify it.  If you can, instantiate in the method you are using and close it.